# Printing selected Component of JFrame to Printer

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5gRlPuet22mRmNHRmExNDNSNjA/edit?usp=sharing) Application Developed in Java.

I want to print only some Components, for example "Customer Name", "The Table" and the "Date".

I have gone through [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584548/can-any-one-help-printing-a-jframe-with-all-its-component-in-java-program) but I am not able to print properly.

Comment: You're going to have problems.  `JTable` has special requirements when it comes to been printed, as the table may not fit onto a single page...A better strategy might be to user the header/footer capabilities of the `JTable` printing API, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544013/how-to-print-a-jtable-object-in-the-java-application/14544898#14544898)

Comment: And what about printing other components?

Comment: I wouldn't, I'd use the header/footer capabilities to print the name and date as text...

Comment: Can u please give me a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few minutes spent reading [How to use tables/printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#printing), would have allowed you to produce something similar to this example...

Printed output...

[image: Printed]

Screen output...

[image: Screen]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class CopyTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CopyTable();
    }

    public CopyTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTable table;
        private JTextField customer;
        private JSpinner date;

        public TestPane() {

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            for (int index = 0; index < 26; index++) {
                model.addColumn((char) (index + 65));
            }

            for (int row = 0; row < 26; row++) {
                Vector rowData = new Vector();
                for (int col = 0; col < 26; col++) {
                    rowData.add(row + "x" + col);
                }
                model.addRow(rowData);
            }

            table = new JTable(model);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date initDate = calendar.getTime();
            Date earliestDate = calendar.getTime();
            calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 200);
            Date latestDate = calendar.getTime();
            SpinnerModel spinnerModel = new SpinnerDateModel(
                            initDate,
                            earliestDate,
                            latestDate,
                            Calendar.YEAR);

            date = new JSpinner();
            date.setModel(spinnerModel);
            date.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(date, "dd/MM/yyyy"));

            customer = new JTextField(10);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            add(new JLabel("Customer:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Date:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(customer, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(date, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new JScrollPane(table), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            JButton print = new JButton("Print");
            add(print, gbc);

            print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Customer: " + customer.getText() + " | Date: " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date.getValue()));
                    try {
                        table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, null, true, null, true);
                    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That was awesome @MadProgrammer! Was trying for something like this. Was lazy for reading. But now you made me understand reading give you all the answers. :) Thanks Brother.

Comment: I don't know about "all the answers", but it will certainly give you ideas and directions to try ;)

Comment: Thumps Up for the help! :)