# java prints Jtable with no borders above columns and rows

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, noborder

I have JTable which looks correct in program, but then I print it where is no borders above columns and rows only one border above all table.

Here is print code:

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Print Report");
MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Page{0,number,integer}");
try {
    registras_table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer);
} catch (PrinterException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(pagrindinis.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

How to set that borders for printing? Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977871/printing-selected-component-of-jframe-to-printer/24978159#24978159) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580954/how-to-print-selected-rows-jtable/26581137#26581137) both seem to work okay...

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this didn't helped me, I added UIManager, but it prints it same, maybe somehow I need to add borders manually only for printing? I didn't see anything like that in your examples.

Comment: Or maybe that borders is not really black because I can print only black.

Comment: Oh that was that, I selected to print everything in black and it printed borders -.-. Sorry for your spent time.