# Pinting in java a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe

Can any one help in how to print a `JFrame` on A4 Size paper in java. I have created a `JFrame` for printing a bill, but it is not working.
I tried to use `Printable` interface but it doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241711/setting-print-size-of-a-jlabel-and-put-a-jradiobutton-on-the-print/22242658#22242658) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241711/setting-print-size-of-a-jlabel-and-put-a-jradiobutton-on-the-print/22244116#22244116) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058738/print-jlabels-icon-in-a-printer-using-a-button/22059079#22059079) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764634/printing-a-jframe-and-its-components/12765916#12765916)

Comment: or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904518/fit-scale-jcomponent-to-page-being-printed/17961911#17961911)?

Comment: Or use something like Jasper Reports

Comment: Or you could use `JTable`, for [exmaple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580954/how-to-print-selected-rows-jtable/26581137#26581137) or [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977871/printing-selected-component-of-jframe-to-printer/24978159#24978159)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print just text you can use

```
JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
jtp.setBackground(Color.white);
jtp.setText(text);//Set text to print.
try {
    jtp.print(null, null, true, null, null, true);
} catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you actually want to print the entire JFrame you could try taking a screen shot of the user's screen and crop it to the JFrame or do [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/swing-obtain-image-of-jframe) and then use something like [**this**](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Printanimageout.htm) to print the image.

Comment: Or simply call `print` on the `JFrame`, but the problem there is you would need to resize the frame so as it make sure it could fit within the boundaries of A4 sheet of paper, which seems to be, at least, half the question here

Comment: Okay... then find how many pixels can fit on the A4 paper then take the longer side of the the JFrame and re-size to fit then resize the other side proportionality.

Comment: thanx all ,i got the idea